# The __init__() misbehavior?

Tags: python

I'm facing strange issue with my code bellow. I simple cannot understand, why the `simpleFiled` attribute of `myClass` remain "prepoluated" from previous "round".

Code:

```
class myClass:
    simpleField = []
    name = ''

    def __init__(self,simple_field=[]):
         self.simpleField = simple_field
         print('In __init__ %s ' % str(simple_field))


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name+' '.join(str(self.simpleField))

def fill(name='default'):
    m = myClass()
    m.name = name
    for i in range(0,5):
        m.simpleField.append(i)
    return m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0,2):
        m = fill('round '+str(i))
        print(m.__repr__())
```

Output (I numbered lines for better understanding)

```
1. In __init__ []
2. round 0[ 0 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   4 ]
3. In __init__ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4. round 1[ 0 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   4 ,   0 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   4 ]
```

Lines 1 and 2 are pretty obvious and no magic over here. I cannot understand why in line 3 I have received such a `simple_field` values. As I can see in my code I create the instance of the class without any arguments - `m = myClass()`

Thank you for any advice

Y

Answer (score 1):

```py
def print_with_extra(lst=[]):
    lst.append("extra")
    print(lst)

print_with_extra(["apple"])  # ['apple', 'extra']
print_with_extra() # ['extra']
print_with_extra() # ['extra', 'extra']
```

The default arguments to functions in Python evaluate once - when the function is defined.

Lists are mutable, and `.append` will change the instance it operates upon.

Therefore, instead of creating a new empty list, `print_with_extra` reuses a single default value initialized to an empty list once, and keeps all the appended elements from the results of default calls there.

The same is happening in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a mutable Type (list) as standard value - it's created once upon definition of your function and remains the same instance on every call. Change it to be `None` and define it as `[]` in the function body `if simple_field is None`